# Could I export model from console in blender?

Tags: model, command-line-interface, blender, fbx

Could i use blender to export model to .fbx format via console?

something like: blender.exe myModel.blend --output model.fbx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Blender 2.90 and up this script will export a scene as an FBX file for you.

**export_fbx.py:**

```
import bpy
import sys

print("Blender export scene in FBX Format in file "+sys.argv[-1])

# Doc can be found here: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.export_scene.html
bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=sys.argv[-1])
```

To invoke it with blender you can use the following command:

```
blender <your_scene>.blend --background --python export_fbx.py -- <your_scene>.fbx
```

The python script is the minimum you can get away with for exporting your scene. There are a lot of parameters you can pass to the `export_scene.fbx()` function and it does not handle mutliple input and output files.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, you could, but in non-trivial way. What i mean by that, is, as it says [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html) in **Python Options**, you can execute python script (as file, or as passed string) from a command line. Example:

```
blender --background --python myscript.py
```

Your script will be executed in `--background` mode - that means without even opening Blender GUI. So you can use Blender as import-export module. Basically you can use anything that is in `bpy` module in such a way. Have a nice time!

---

**EDIT**

> something like: blender.exe myModel.blend --output model.fbx

Link, that i have provided, also contains all other command line options for Blender. At least i haven't found direct import-export option here. So i think you will anyway need to write python script.

Comment: What script should i use to export to fbx? Is it already in blender? How could I run it?

Comment: For controlling blender in python script, use `bpy`. It's blender python library, that allows you to communicate with blender within code. To run python script, using blender, type this into your cmd: `<path to blender> --background --python myscript.py`. you need to pass path where yor blender exe is instead of <path to blender>, and myscript.py is the path where your script is.

Comment: I understand what you want to do, but i'm afraid that there is no really "quick'n'easy" way to do this. For your purposes, https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.export_scene.html and https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.import_scene.html is good to read. Let me know if you have any problems or questions.